# Run application in local server

Tags: javascript, deployment, server, mean-stack, host

i've simple MeanStack application which is running E2E as expected.
I've upload this application to Heroku and its working well.
This is was that simple since Heroku handle the `deploy and build` etc.

Now I got **internal server** with **URL** that I need to host the application there and got also some URL to call it.
(not in Heroku , now in my **own server**)

In this server I've some folder which I should put the application there and run it
my question is:

which **steps** I should do in order to provide the ability to consume the application with this provided URL from my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have your app running on heroku, you can just replicate how heroku deployed it.

- On your server, install required packages ([nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/), [monogodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/))
- Push your code on server, using git/ftp or a bundle
- On your machine, go to project dir and run `npm start` which should start your app
- In order to make your app restart even after errors, you can use [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) or [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)
- Configure your network/firewall settings to allow traffic through proper ports
- Bind your IP to the URL using DNS records
- Voila! Your app should be up on the URL.

Though there are better ways to deploy it using [docker containers](https://blog.giantswarm.io/getting-started-with-docker-and-meanjs/), this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you , 1+ , can you please elaborate(or provide some referance how can I do that) on how I combine/map  the URL which provided to me (by the team which provided the server) to my app, for example when you deploy to heroku you get a URL for application by them...

Comment: You need to create an A record pointing to your IP address in your DNS records. Mostly this is a web-ui provided by your server providers. But in your case, seems like another team is handling all that, so you can ask them to create.